# ASP.NET Core Javascript Throwing Status 404 readyState 4 error (Apparently) my machine only

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I think a more appropriate title is my private JavaScript Hell.

First off I am new to JavaScript.  Never used it before this attempt.

Three or four weeks back when I first encountered this error I posted on ASP.Net forums and the good folks helped me out there.  However after a full week of one hour a day concentrating on this issue I am no further advanced than I was three weeks ago even with their help.  The issue seems to be either I am transcribing something incorrectly and I am blind (this wouldn't surprise me) or the error is specific to some aspect within my machine.

First the set up.  I have a controller for jobs where I am wanting to cascade a drop down box content based on a preceeding selection.  The two drop downs involved are Site and Waterbodys.  The relevant part of the controller is:

```
    public class JobsController : Controller
{
    private readonly EVAContext _context;

    public JobsController(EVAContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }  
     // GET: Jobs/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewData["SiteID"] = new SelectList(_context.Sites, "SiteID", "SiteName");
        ViewData["WaterBodyID"] = new SelectList(_context.WaterBodys, "WaterBodyID", "WBName");
        ViewData["DepartmentID"] = new SelectList(_context.Departments, "DepartmentID", "iDepartment");

        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult GetWaterBody(int siteID)
    {
        var waterBody = new List<WaterBody>();
        waterBody = getWaterBodyFromDataBaseBySiteID(siteID);
        return Json(waterBody);

    }

    public List<WaterBody> getWaterBodyFromDataBaseBySiteID(int siteID)
    {
        return _context.WaterBodys.ToList();
    }
```

Within the associated view I have :

```
    @model EVA.Models.Job

    @{
ViewData["Title"] = "Add Job";
   }

   <h2>Add Job</h2>

   <form asp-action="Create">
      <div class="form-horizontal">
            <hr />
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="OrderNumber" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="OrderNumber" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="OrderNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="SiteID" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select asp-for="SiteID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.SiteID" id="site-target">
                <option>---Select Site First---</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="WaterBodyID" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select asp-for="WaterBodyID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.WaterBodyID" id="wb-target">
                <option>---Select Site First---</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="DepartmentID" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select asp-for="DepartmentID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.DepartmentID">
                <option>---Select Department---</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="JobNumber" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="JobNumber" class="form-control" value="1234" />
            <span asp-validation-for="JobNumber" class="text-danger" />
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">    
        <label asp-for="JobDescription" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="JobDescription" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="JobDescription" class="text-danger" />
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
    <div>
<a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
   </div>

   @section Scripts {



       <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#site-target").on("change", function () { 
        $list = $("#wb-target");
        $.ajax({
            url: "Jobs/GetWaterBody",//Core0309 is my controller name
            type: "GET",
            data: { id: $("#site-target").val() }, //id of the site which is        used to extract waterbodies
            traditional: true,
            success: function (result) {
                $list.empty();
                $.each(result, function (i, item) {
                    $list.append('<option value="' + item["WaterBodyID"] + '"> ' + item["WBName"] + ' </option>');          //Must be lowercase ,if not ,you will get value 'Undefined'
                });
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(XMLHttpRequest.status); 
                alert(textStatus);
            },

            //error: function () {
               // alert("Danger!! Will Robertson Danger!!!!!!!!!!!");
           // }
        });
    });
});
  </script>
   <!--<script src="~/js/WaterBody.js"></script>-->

@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
   }
```

I previously had Waterbody.js which was also returning the same 404 based error.

What is frustrating and has led me here is on the ASP.Net forum the people there have copied my code to their own machine and it is running without error I am told.  Although they are using a different set of drop downs.

I am seriously feeling like I am bashing my head against the wall.  I have tried every suggestion, spent hours looking at examples on line and making minor changes to try and find the culprit but nothing works.

I am left with these questions:

1:  Is my JobController code correct?  Have I inadvertently introduced a stuff up there?

2:  Is the script correct?  I added alerts at one stage and I keep getting the idea the error is in the url but don't know that.

3:  Is there some reference or dependency I may be missing on my machine specifically?

4:  Some other question I haven't considered as I am still too new to this?

Help please.  I am at the point where I must get this working to be able to move on with the balance of the project.  Thanks in advance.  I honestly hope this is a silly thing I done.

Bit of an update...

I added some alerts  and they are indicating the error is occurring on $.ajax line.

```
  alert("Inside")
        $list = $("#wb-target");
        alert("aferlist")
        $.ajax({
```

Afterlist is firing but the next alert "Ajax" doesn't fire.

Comment: Are you able to hit a breakpoint in the controller when calling the service method from your javascript?  Also, try changing the parameter name in GetWaterBody to just "id" instead of "siteID".

Comment: Also, try using the full path to the method including http localhost etc.

Comment: GET http://localhost:62233/Jobs/Jobs/GetWaterBody?id=2 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery.js:9172
ajax @ jquery.js:8653
(anonymous) @ Create:153
dispatch @ jquery.js:4732
elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4544
ListPicker._handleMouseUp @ about:blank:544
jquery.js:9097 [Violation] Handler took 1479ms of runtime (150ms allowed)
[Violation] Long running JavaScript task took 1479ms

Comment: I did say I am new to this...
Are you able to hit a breakpoint in the controller when calling the service method from your javascript? Also, try changing the parameter name in GetWaterBody to just "id" instead of "siteID". – TrevorBrooks 43 mins ago   Uhmmm....               How?  Not used breakpoints yet

Comment: try localhost:62233/api/Jobs/GetWaterBody/2

Comment: Also, your controller should inherit from ApiController instead of Controller ie. public class JobsController: ApiController

Comment: It's ok if you're new to this there's just a lot of things to make sure to get it right.